# forward-declaration in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, forward-declaration

My program include two main parts. The first one is c++ class definition in the DLL, the other one is the core program. After each DLL is loaded on the core program, the Proxy class will fill the class description into the data structure in the core program, which is solved by using the keyword "extern"

I got a problem of declaration order  with the error messages.
in the code line: "typedef map method_map;"
 1. error: ‘proxy’ was not declared in this scope 
 2. error: template argument 2 is invalid in the code line:

```
typedef common_object *maker_t();
extern map< string, maker_t* > factory;


//This method_map is used to store all the method structure data of each class
//method: class_name, method_name, function pointer
//I got two errors here:
//1. "ERROR: ‘proxy’ was not declared in this scope"
//2. "ERROR: ‘error: template argument 2 is invalid"
typedef map<string, proxy::method> method_map;
//this class_map contain the methods description for each class.
//this class_map is declared in the core program.
//after the class in this dll is loaded on the core program,
//it would automatically fill its descriptino in here
extern  map<string, method_map> class_map_;

// our global factory
template<typename T>
class proxy {
public:
typedef int (T::*mfp)(lua_State *L);
typedef struct {
    const char *class_name;
    const char *method_name;
    mfp mfunc;
} method;

proxy() {
    std::cout << "circle proxy" << endl;
    // the loop for filling the methods information of the class T
    method_map method_map_;
    for (method *m = T::methods;m->method_name; m++) {
        method m1; //specific information about each method
        m1.class_name = T::className;
        m1.method_name = m->method_name;
        m1.mfunc = m->mfunc;
        method_map_[m1.method_name] = m1; //assign m1 into the method map
    }
    //Assign methods description of the T class into the class_map
    class_map_[T::class_name] = method_map_;
}
};
```

I hope to see your advises about this problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`method_map` and `class_map_` will need to be nested inside `proxy` (or some other template), since they depend on another nested type (`method`), which in turn depends on the template parameter.

If they didn't (e.g. if `proxy` were a class rather than a template), then they would need to be declared after `proxy` in order to use types declared there.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried to declare class_map_ inside the class proxy, but I got the message error due to class_map_ is declared with the keyword "extern", which can not be put inside a class. Could you provide some other suggestions. I hope to see your reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

forward define/declare the `class proxy;` before `typedef map<string, proxy::method> method_map;`

like so:

```
    template<class T>
    class proxy;
    typedef map<string, proxy::method> method_map;
```

Comment: How will this work? How will the compiler know what is `method` inside `proxy`.

Comment: @Dani by having something called an interface.

Comment: @Aniket: I tried your solution as following:                               t                             template<typename T>
    class proxy;
    typedef map<string, proxy::method> method_map;                           but I got the same error message "template argument 2  is invalid" in the code line "typedef...". I think the reason is that proxy::method needs an template argument. Could you provide another suggestions. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1859177 `typedef map<string, proxy<your_type>::method> method_map`

Comment: @Aniket: so sad, I don't know my_type is what. It could be any kind of class in the future. I tried proxy<T>::method, but I got the error: "'T' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @user1859177 I will give you another way to do this: put `typedef map<string, proxy<T>::method> method_map;` inside `class proxy`, and create/use a function `map<string,proxy<T>::method> *getMap()` that gets the instance of the map in your program

Comment: It could be helpful in another case. Unfortunately, in my case, the class_map_ have put outside the class proxy because this class_map_ is declared with the keyword "extern", which means that class_map_ will references to class_map in the core program after the dll is loaded on the core program. So, I have to declare class_map outside my proxy class. Any suggestions? I hope to see your points soon. Thanks

Comment: @khanhhh89 the problem is with your code then. having an extern is not the correct way _mostly_. You can use an object oriented pattern called Factory combined with a singleton. The problem _really_ is your template, which isn't resolved until its used. And hence the `extern` can't be resolved until template parameters are resolved. I think you can see where I am getting to.